# Swing: JPopupMenu unselect text when popup on JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, popup

I try to add "standard" cut/copy/paste popup menu to JFormattedTextField.

Paste works as expected, but cut and copy - doesn't. The problem is that during poping up menu JFormattedTextField lost it's selection. Any ideas why this happened and how to fix it?

My code:

```
public class SwingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new TestPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class TestPanel extends JPanel {
        public TestPanel(){
            JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField("    ");
             JFormattedTextField component = field;
             final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
             JMenuItem item;
             item = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
             item.setText("Copy");
             item.setEnabled(component.getSelectionStart() != component.getSelectionEnd());
             menu.add(item);
             item = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
             item.setText("Cut");
             item.setEnabled(component.isEditable() && component.getSelectionStart() != component.getSelectionEnd());
             menu.add(item);
             item = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
             item.setText("Paste");
             item.setEnabled(component.isEditable());
             menu.add(item);

            field.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
            add(field, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Quick investigation shows that above code works differently under OS X (my OS) and Windows (most commenters OS). I'm looking for safe and cross-platform way to show popup window.

Comment: Where is the code for action that is performed?

Comment: side note .`border layout` is not the default layout manager for jpanel .you have to set layout to border for `TestPanel`

Comment: Seems to work okay for me, but I wouldn't be disabling the menu items BEFORE anything has been applied to the field ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure is this your problem. but,

if your problem is copy/cut menu is disabled when you right click ,it happen because you set visibility when gui start (constructor).so there is no text and cut copy items get disabled and they never become enabled.you should add a listener and should set visibility when action fire.so when you right-click menu items will be visible/hidden on your conditions.

for example

```
public class SwingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new TestPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    public TestPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField("    ");
        JFormattedTextField component = field;
        final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem item1, item2, item3;
        item1 = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
        item1.setText("Copy");

        menu.add(item1);
        item2 = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
        item2.setText("Cut");

        menu.add(item2);
        item3 = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
        item3.setText("Paste");

        menu.add(item3);
        menu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                item1.setEnabled(component.getSelectionStart() != component.getSelectionEnd());
                item2.setEnabled(component.isEditable() && component.getSelectionStart() != component.getSelectionEnd());
                item3.setEnabled(component.isEditable());
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            }
        });
        field.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
        add(field, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

side note :

1) avoid declaring jpanel as a static if you don't have reason .make it as instance.

2) `border layout` is not the default layout manager for jpanel .you have to set layout to border for TestPanel.

in your code your panel's layout is flow layout(default) but you call

```
add(field, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

to correct this you need to set border layout like this

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: My problem is not that copy/paste is disabled, but that this menu items doesn't work. If i select put text in the field, select it and "say" copy from popup menu, nothing happened. What I see is that during popping up process text selection in the field is clearing. Again, didn't test it on Windows. Under OS X it works as I described.

Comment: @FoxyBOA hmm can you test my above example code and tell does it work ? or not ?

Comment: Tested under Windows. You fixed Windows related issue. Unfortunately, OS X behaviour differ. And yes, I'm looking for universal way to show this popup windows for Linux, OS X and Windows.

Comment: @FoxyBOA  you should test what part doesn't work in os x .`DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction()` or popup menu .i can't test under os x . i'm not sure why it doesn't work on osx .is that your complete code ??? if so i can't understand how did you click copy menu item ..because it should be enabled before you click

Comment: As I described above, when popup shows, text selection is clearing and copy action doesn't work.